# can't create django app on openshift

Tags: django, openshift

Trying to create the django app on openshift.

Doesn't work with python 3.3.

Say:

> The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 54****** -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c23' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' returned an error. rc=255 .Last 10 kB of build output: v/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Django-1.4-py3.3.egg/django/contrib/admindocs/views.py", line 321 except template.InvalidTemplateLibrary

Some time ago it was worked, and I had Django 1.6 cartridge on python 3.3 on openshift. Just to try recreated it... Something went wrong.

Comment: It looks like it has Django 1.4 installed, not Django 1.6. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: May be. But I only use "Create application", and can select only python version, not the django version.

Comment: Look's like standart Django cartridge doesn't work on python 3.3. I was trye the community-build "Django 1.6 and Python 3 on OpenShift Quickstart" (https://github.com/rancavil/django-py3-openshift-quickstart.git), and it's look installable

Comment: Spending a lot of time, I threw openschift, and moved on to pythonanywhere.